# Unable to login to Sitecore Content Hub due to basic authentication set to false and external authentication not working

Tags: content-hub

I'm unable to login to Content Hub due to my external authentication which is set to Sitecore, routing to the not found page and I have disabled basic authentication.

So I'm locked out of the content hub, due to which can't change any configuration, Can anyone please provide any suggestion on how I can login into Content hub?

Comment: Is it your super user account which is been lock out and no one else has a super user account to create and account for you? In that case reaching out to Sitecore Support seems to be the option, they might be able to help creating another super user account for you.